# Save only first and last state in Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra

What I've read about Cassandra is that `insert` and `update` are almost identical.
If `update` did not find rows filtered by `where` section it just inserts the record.

I want to store initial and last "state" of orders I store in database. (note that I insert batches of 500-2000 rows at a time).
Knowing Cassandra abilities - is it possible to make this possible without any logic on application side? I mean application would just insert records without knowing anything about "state" of order it inserts\updates.

I tried to make `modify_dt timestamp` column which would've been null initially, but Cassandra doesn't have this type natively, so you cannot use this value in `where` section. Also I tried to make `initial_state boolean` column, but didn't find the way to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQL `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements are identical. In fact, ALL Cassandra writes are inserts under the hood - even for `DELETE` statements.

In any case, your statement around:

> *If `UPDATE` did not find rows ...*

is incorrect. Cassandra does not do a read-before-write (except for conditional statements which I'll talk about next) and it does not know whether the record already exists so just inserts the record regardless.

For your use case where you want to store some (1) initial state and (2) the current (last) state, I'd suggest simply storing those values in the table. Here's an example of what it would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_reference text,
    initial_state text,
    current_state text,
    PRIMARY KEY (order_reference)
)
```

Updating the current state is easy enough with:

```
UPDATE orders
  SET current_state = ?
  WHERE order_reference = ?
```

When it comes to the initial state, you will need to use a conditional statement known as a [lightweight transaction](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html) (LWT). LWTs allow you to specify an `IF` clause with `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements to perform a compare-and-set (CAS).

LWT is the only time that Cassandra performs a read-before-write. It needs to read the data to compare it to some condition, and will only write it (set) if the condition is true.

A typical use case for lightweight transactions is to only create a new record in the `users` table if the `username` is not already allocated to someone with the `IF NOT EXISTS` condition.

In your case, we only want to set the initial state if the order does not exist yet:

```
INSERT INTO orders (order_reference, initial_state)
  VALUES (?, ?)
  IF NOT EXISTS
```

The record will only be created for new orders. If an order already exists, the conditional `INSERT` will not overwrite the existing record. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this would be possible without any additional logic, but can you tell us what you need to accomplish? If you want to avoid overriding values, you do have the ability to perform a CAS operation in Cassandra using IF NOT EXISTS, but you'd need additional logic to see what actually existed if this is a necessity.  In general though, the initial state of a record will only hang around in sstables after an Insert/Update, so you'd only be able to retrieve this via a tool like sstabledump, and only until compaction removed it.  Cassandra uses timestamp resolution, so once an updated record is inserted, you can only retrieve the most recent value through normal methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also came up with such answer for myself.
I have a series of data, which can mutate. I want to store only initial state of this data and the last one, without intermediate ones. Not only select them, but to store.

Comment: Definitely nothing built-in that would handle this, you'd have to store that initial value elsewhere with some additional logic.  Best of luck